# Express Nested Router not calling sub functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following router.use calls in one of my routers

```js
router.use("/:collection/", (req) => {
    return require(`./${req.params.collection}`);
});
```

and that calls in this example, example.js

example.js is as follows:

```js
const header = require("../../header"); //gets our header that declares everything

const router = header.express.Router(); //makes our router for collections requests


console.log("123");


///The Following is when a name is requested
router.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("test");
    res.json({msg:"hi"});
    next();
});


module.exports = router; //makes our router avialable
```

you'd expect when:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/example/test
```

is request that it would write in the console something to the effect of:

```
123
test
```

and I would get the response:

```
{msg:"hi"}
```

Instead the console gets just:

```
123
```

written and there is no response.

It seems the

```
 router.get
```

in the example.js is never called, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, instead of

```js
router.use("/:collection/", (req) => {
    return require(`./${req.params.collection}`);
});
```

I use

```
router.get("/:collection", (req, res) => {
  //this is my other call that will do stuff in the parent file
  //we don't call next because it is already matched, otherwise we call next
});

router.use("/:collection/", (req, res, next) =>{ //says if it gets here pass on the info
  router.use("/:collection/", require(`./${req.params.collection}`)); //then route
  next();
});
```